# Subsonic 3/ASP.net MVC issue trying to override class column properties

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3

I am using Subsonic 3 (T4 template) to generate the models for my mvc app.  However the default template does not allow for nullable columns, so when I go to save the record it errors out if a nullable datetime column is blank.  ([See this post...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975457/subsonic-3-asp-net-mvc-trying-to-save-a-null-value-in-a-datetime-column)

Question:  What is the best practice to handle this?
Option 1:  Change the template to check if it is a nullable column and decorate the datatype with ?  That would take me out of sync with any changes Rob makes to his templates which I might want

Option 2:  Is there a way to override the column in a partial class?

Other options?

Comment: Are you using the latest version from google code and which template?

Comment: Thanks Adam.  No I wasn't using the latest (see Rob's post below), and sorry for not being more specific.  The template was classes.tt, which generates classes.cs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grab the latest from the trunk it's been fixed - the templates will set nullable for nullable columns.